# Installation fails: informix sdk 4.50.FC7, pdo_informix 1.3.6, PHP8

Tags: pdo, informix

I'm trying to install PDO_INFORMIX 1.3.6 with Informix-SDK 4.50.FC7 on PHP 8
and I'm running in issues even though I stick to the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally made it work with these settings. Might be not the optimum, but it worked for me.

```
# download informix sdk, go to content
./installclientsdk -i console
#               ^^^^^^^^^ documentation states installclientsdk -console

# install with default settings

# for PDO: Specify Client Dir as env var 
export INFORMIXDIR=/opt/IBM/Informix_Client-SDK

# add path which actually contains the files
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$INFORMIXDIR/incl/cli:$INFORMIXDIR/lib/cli:$INFORMIXDIR/lib/esql:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
#                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cli is here, the documentation doesnt specify this

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH


# pecl / pdo
cd /install/PDO_INFORMIX-1.3.6
phpize
./configure --with-pdo-informix=/opt/IBM/Informix_Client-SDK
make
make install

# add `extension=pdo_informix.so` to the php.ini
```

Comment: [In this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71646887) you can find a docker-compose & dockerfile to set up a testsystem