# how to make informix pdo work even though make test fails on debian machine and docker

Tags: php, pdo, informix

I try installing Informix with PDO locally and on docker, each way leads to the same failing tests.

I'm not sure if 'just' the tests are failing because some configuration would be needed to make them run, while the client / pdo would work fine if I start working on these.

**Update:**
It turns out that the PDO works even though the make test all fail.
Meaning with below Dockerfile it is possible to spin up a PHP-8.0 Informix 4.50 PDO_INFORMIX 1.3.6 container (you need to download the [IBM Informix CSDK](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/informix-client-software-development-kit-client-sdk-and-informix-connect-system-requirements) and the [PDO](https://pecl.php.net/package/PDO_INFORMIX) first)

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM php:8.0.17-fpm-buster

# Provide Files
ADD ./PDO_INFORMIX-1.3.6.tgz /informix-pdo
ADD ./ibm.csdk.4.50.FC7.LNX.tar /informix-sdk

# Prepare Install SDK
ENV INFORMIXDIR=/opt/IBM/Informix_Client-SDK
RUN apt update && apt -y install rpm && mkdir -p /var/lib/rpm && rpm --initdb
RUN apt -y install libncurses5

# Install SDK
RUN cd /informix-sdk && \
    ./installclientsdk -i silent -DLICENSE_ACCEPTED=TRUE -DUSE_OPENSSL_CONSOLE="Use GSKit" -DUSER_INSTALL_DIR=/opt/IBM/Informix_Client-SDK -DCHOSEN_FEATURE_LIST=SDK,SDK-CPP,SDK-CPP-DEMO,SDK-ESQL,SDK-ESQL-DEMO,SDK-ESQL-ACM,SDK-LMI,SDK-ODBC,SDK-ODBC-DEMO,DBA-DBA,SDK-NETCORE,GLS,GLS-WEURAM,GLS-EEUR,GLS-JPN,GLS-KOR,GLS-CHN,GLS-OTH -DCHOSEN_INSTALL_FEATURE_LIST=SDK,SDK-CPP,SDK-CPP-DEMO,SDK-ESQL,SDK-ESQL-DEMO,SDK-ESQL-ACM,SDK-LMI,SDK-ODBC,SDK-ODBC-DEMO,DBA-DBA,SDK-NETCORE,GLS,GLS-WEURAM,GLS-EEUR,GLS-JPN,GLS-KOR,GLS-CHN,GLS-OTH -DCHOSEN_INSTALL_SET=Custom

# Install PDO, add extension to php, 
RUN cd /informix-pdo/PDO_INFORMIX-1.3.6/ && \
    phpize && \
    ./configure --with-pdo-informix=/opt/IBM/Informix_Client-SDK && \
    make && \
    make install && \
    echo "extension=pdo_informix" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-informix.ini && \
    kill -USR2 1 && \ 
    make test

CMD ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
```

*Note*:
I add the `pdo_informix extension` and `restart php` before `make test`, as I need to have the extension enabled. Without doing so there is no difference in `make test`.

**Testresults**

```
root@555b0fd88bc6:/informix-pdo/PDO_INFORMIX-1.3.6# make test
/bin/bash /informix-pdo/PDO_INFORMIX-1.3.6/libtool --mode=install cp ./pdo_informix.la /informix-pdo/PDO_INFORMIX-1.3.6/modules
cp ./.libs/pdo_informix.so /informix-pdo/PDO_INFORMIX-1.3.6/modules/pdo_informix.so
cp ./.libs/pdo_informix.lai /informix-pdo/PDO_INFORMIX-1.3.6/modules/pdo_informix.la
PATH="$PATH:/sbin" ldconfig -n /informix-pdo/PDO_INFORMIX-1.3.6/modules
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Libraries have been installed in:
   /informix-pdo/PDO_INFORMIX-1.3.6/modules

If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries
in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and
specify the full pathname of the library, or use the `-LLIBDIR'
flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
   - add LIBDIR to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
     during execution
   - add LIBDIR to the `LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
     during linking
   - use the `-Wl,--rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
   - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to `/etc/ld.so.conf'

See any operating system documentation about shared libraries for
more information, such as the ld(1) and ld.so(8) manual pages.
----------------------------------------------------------------------

Build complete.
Don't forget to run 'make test'.


=====================================================================
PHP         : /usr/local/bin/php
PHP_SAPI    : cli
PHP_VERSION : 8.0.17
ZEND_VERSION: 4.0.17
PHP_OS      : Linux - Linux 555b0fd88bc6 4.9.0-18-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.303-1 (2022-03-07) x86_64
INI actual  : /informix-pdo/PDO_INFORMIX-1.3.6/tmp-php.ini
More .INIs  :
CWD         : /informix-pdo/PDO_INFORMIX-1.3.6
Extra dirs  :
VALGRIND    : Not used
=====================================================================

All tests fail
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the process, but since "All tests fail", I need to ask: do you have an operational Informix environment with an Informix server configured?  Have you set $INFORMIXDIR and $INFORMIXSERVER at minimum, and possibly other Informix-related environment variables?  The $INFORMIXSERVER variable wouldn't be needed to compile the code (but $INFORMIXDIR would), but $INFORMIXSERVER probably would be needed to run the tests successfully.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, true, I had to provide INFORMIXSERVER in the enclosing docker-compose, in which I have the informix environment from [this container](https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/informix-developer-database/#!)
I guess the only open topic is the failing tests (all tests red, except the two tests which expect failure bc password)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this docker-compose and the dockerfile mentioned in the question above, a workable solution can be established.
Ensure the tmp folder for the DB exists and can be written to

```
mkdir -p /tmp/ibm-storage/extvol
chmod 777 /tmp/ibm-storage/extvol
```

To roll out a test db, wait for docker-compose to finish, then run `docker-compose exec db /opt/ibm/informix/bin/dbaccessdemo`

```
version: '3.8'

services: 
  app:
    build: 
      context: ./app 
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-php8
    volumes:
      - ./:/opt/scripts
    environment: 
      - INFORMIX_PASSWORD=in4mix
    
  db:
    image: ibmcom/informix-developer-database:latest 
    environment: 
      - INFORMIX_PASSWORD=in4mix
      - LICENSE=accept
      - DBSERVERNAME=db
      - INFORMIXSERVER=db
    volumes:
      - /tmp/ibm-storage/extvol:/opt/ibm/data
    ports: 
      - 9088:9088
      - 9089:9089
      - 27017:27017
      - 27018:27018 
      - 27883:27883
    
# Custom network
networks:
  default:
    name: my-net
```